# Reporting text in citations rather than numbers

Tags: bibtex, citing

I am trying to convert the quoting on my text in latex in a text format rather than the standard numeric format of latex. For instance where I now have:

> [...] complex generics both from a normative point of view (e.g. [28]) and from achemical point of view (e.g. [16], [2])

I would like to return something like:

> [...] complex generics both from a normative point of view (e.g. Stiglitz et al, 2020) and from a chemical point of view (e.g. Dubois et al, 2015; Acemoglu D. Linn S., 2004)

I am working with bibtex and have a bibliography in a .bib file apart.

Is there a way to switch from one format to the other?

Thank you a lot

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which bibliography style you employ at present and whether or not you employ a citation management package such as `cite` or `natbib`.

Comment: @Mico Hi and thanks for the reply. I am using `\documentclass[12pt]{article}`, `\bibliographystyle{plain}` referring to an external bibliography called bibliografia.bib. Finally, in the text I am citing with `\cite{}`

Comment: @Mico maybe a further detail is that, after `\bibliography{plain}` I am using: `\bibliography{bibliografia} \nocite`

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using the `plain` bibliography style (and, apparently, no citation management package such as `cite`), and since you appear to be ok with the way the bibliographic entries are formatted and with using BibTeX, I would like to suggest that you

- load the `natbib` citation management package with the options `authoryear` and `round` -- *viz.*, run `\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}`;
- change the instruction `\bibliographystyle{plain}` to `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}`; and
- keep using `\cite` (or `\citet`) to create text-style citation call-outs and start using `\citep` to create parenthesis-style citation call-outs.

E.g., to generate "(e.g., Dubois et al, 2015; Acemoglu and Linn, 2004)", assuming the entries have keys `dubois-etal:2015` and `acemoglu-linn:2004`, respectively, you'd write

```
\citep[e.g.,][]{dubois-etal:2015,acemoglu-linn:2004}
```

For the very first compilation run after changing the argument of `\bibliographystyle`, it may be necessary to delete the .aux and .bbl files.

---

Here's an MWE (minimum working example) that shows how this setup should work.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{abc:2000,
  author = "Anna Author and Brenda Brandywine and Carla Carlsson",
  title  = "Thoughts",
  year   = 2000,
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}

\begin{document}
\citep[e.g.,][]{abc:2000}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you. The problem is that after adding `\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}` and `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` (which by the way seems not to be recognized), the text after citations disappears.  do not have .aux files but only a .bib file. If it might help, I am working with Overleaf.

Comment: @Federico - If there's no bbl file after a compilation cycle (LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more), something must have gone very wrong. Maybe check for typos?

Comment: Hi, you think that somebody can help me for my recent question?